# Java - variable value from one class to another class

Tags: java, variables, getter-setter

I want to transfer a variable value of type List (variable name is seznamRacunov) from one class to another.

Class 1

```
public class UvoziRacun 
{
  private String potRacuna;
  private List<String> seznamRacunov = new ArrayList();

  public void setRacun(List<String> seznamRacunov)
  {
      this.seznamRacunov = seznamRacunov;
  }

  public List<String> getRacun()
  {
      return seznamRacunov;
  }

  public String getPotRacuna()
  {
      return potRacuna;
  }

  public void showDailog()
  {
      try
      {
        JFileChooser racun = new JFileChooser();
        racun.setCurrentDirectory(new File(""));

        racun.setFileFilter(new javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter() 
        {
            public boolean accept(File f) 
            {
                return f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".xml") || f.isDirectory();
            }
            public String getDescription() 
            {
                return "XML Datoteka";
            }
        });

        //racun.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        int r = racun.showOpenDialog(new JFrame());

        if (r == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            potRacuna = racun.getSelectedFile().getPath();
            seznamRacunov.add(potRacuna); //value is stored
        }
        //System.out.print("Racuni: " + seznamRacunov);
      }
      catch(Exception ex){}
  }
}
```

Class 2

```
public class PrikaziRacune extends javax.swing.JFrame 
{
    UvoziRacun rac = new UvoziRacun();

    public PrikaziRacune() 
    {
        initComponents();

        try
        {
            System.out.print(rac.getRacun()); // value is null, why?
            //jLabel2.setText();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){}
}
```

Method `seznamRacunov.add(potRacuna);` store a value into seznamRacunov in Class 1, but the value of list does not pass in class 2 where I called getter. What is wrong?

Comment: Do you want the value or the reference?

Comment: I want the value of list stored inside the first class.

Answer (score 1):

> Method seznamRacunov.add(potRacuna); store a value into seznamRacunov
>   in Class 1, but the value of list does not pass in class 2 where I
>   called getter.

Thats because, you are trying to `get()` your `List` without even calling the `method - showDailog()` which in turn invokes your `add()` method to populate list.

- Make sure, you invoke this method - `showDailog()` to populate the list, before you actually fetch the `List` with `get` method
- Or, it would be better, if you add a `constructor` to your class, which does the task of `initializing` your `List`. Then you can create an instance using that `constructor` and thus you won't have any problem.

**PS**: - You should always have at least a `0-arg constructor` to initialize your fields, rather than `letting` compiler handle this task for you.

And one more thing, you should never, ever engulp your exception by having an `empty` catch block. Else there is no point in catching them. Add a `printStackTrace()` call instead.

```
 public PrikaziRacune() {
    initComponents();

    try
    {
        rac.showDailog();  // Will populate the list
        System.out.print(rac.getRacun()); // You can get the value here.
        //jLabel2.setText();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

- Also, check your `ArrayList` declaration in your first class. You are using `generic type List` on LHS, and a `Raw type ArrayList` on the RHS. Its something that you should avoid.

Have `Generic` type on both the sides: -

```
private List<String> seznamRacunov = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Thank you for advice, I will try first solution. In second solution I do not want to show dialog one more time so it is not a good idea.

Comment: @Strausa Then you need to define a Constructor to initialize your List. Because you are initializing it in `showDailog` method only..